# How does code make an electrical machine work?

Tags: architecture, operating-system, system

I've always wondered how computers use electricity with a sort of "language" to work with an OS and so on.

I've already searched on the Internet, but everything was hard to understand.

Comment: Try to ask at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple way to to explain how a computer works from the high level of a "computer language" to the low level of "electrical signals." That is not to say that the concept is necessarily hard to understand. Fundamental computer systems are many simple constructs that build on one another. I highly recommend [*Introduction to Computing Systems: From Bits and Gates to C and Beyond* (Patt & Patel)](http://a.co/71ebT1H), which I read in an introductory systems course in college.